# $\theta$ Term In 2d for $U(1)$ and $SO(2)$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, topological-field-theory

For the $U(1)$ gauge theory in 2d, there can be a theta term
$$\frac{\theta}{2\pi}\int_{M} dA$$
where $A$ is the $U(1)$ gauge field and $\theta\sim \theta+2\pi$.

However, it is known that $U(1)=SO(2)$, so we can write the $U(1)$ gauge field in terms of $SO(2)$ gauge field, which is related by 
$$A^{SO(2)}_{\mu}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & A_{\mu}\\ -A_{\mu} & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

> But how can we write the theta term using the $SO(2)$ gauge field? Notice that $Tr(A^{SO(2)})=0$, so $\frac{\theta}{2\pi}\int_{M} dTr(A^{SO(2)})=0$ which does not work.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Just define some map $\mathrm{not-a-trace}(A_\mu^{SO(2)}) = A_\mu$ if you really want to write this with $A^{SO(2)}$. What is it you want to know here?

Comment: @ACuriousMind there can be theta term for any $SO(n)$ in fact. But I do not know how to write down such terms. $n=2$ is the simplest case we can study, and a nice thing about SO(2) is that it is isomorphic to U(1). Your way is ok for SO(2), but it does not teach us how to generalize to SO(n). So I think there should be better ways to think about the theta term in terms of SO(2) gauge field only.

Comment: But SO(2) is special in any case because it is Abelian. Abelian things rarely straightforwardly generalize to non-Abelian things. If you actually want to know what the $\theta$ term for any $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ is, I think it would be much more useful if you asked that directly.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying your question and defining some terms please?